# How to use a dash as separator in a Zend_Controller_Router_Route

Tags: zend-framework, routes, url-routing, zend-controller-router

Currently one of my routes looks like this

```
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  'aviso/:url_id/:slug',
  array(
    'module' => 'postulante',
    'controller' => 'aviso',
    'action' => 'ver',
    'url_id' => ':url_id',
    'slug'=> ':slug'
  )
)
```

Now, I want to change the url part and use 'aviso/:slug-:url_id' instead of 'aviso/:url_id/:slug', how can i achieve this.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to do with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex).  If you read through that documentation you'll have enough info to construct the route you want. The very last example they provide is very close to what you need.